# convert terraform HCL variable type=map(any) to JSON

Tags: json, terraform, hcl

I am trying to convert an terraform variable written in HCL to a dynamically generated `tf.json` file containing the variable, but I am running into errors.

HCL version I am trying to convert:

```
variable "accounts" {
  type        = map(any)

  default = {
    acct1     = ["000000000001"]
    acct2     = ["000000000002"]
  }
}
```

I have tried the following format:

```
{
  "variable": {
    "accounts": {
      "type": "map(any)",

      "default": [
        { "acct1": "000000000001" },
        { "acct2": "000000000002"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "variable": {
    "accounts": {
      "type": "map(any)",
      "default": [
        {
          "acct1": ["000000000001"],
          "acct2": ["000000000002"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid default value for variable
│ 
│   on accounts.tf.json line 6, in variable.accounts:
│    6:       "default": [
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: map of any single type required.
```

Is there a tool that will convert HCL to valid `.tf.json` configurations? Or what am I missing on the formatting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specified type for the variable is a `map(any)`, so your default value for the variable must also be a `map(any)`, and cannot be a `list(map(list(string)))`.

```
{
  "variable": {
    "accounts": {
      "type": "map(any)",
      "default": {
        "acct1": ["000000000001"],
        "acct2": ["000000000002"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That would assign a default value of type `object(list(string))` which matches the same `object(list(string))` type structure in your HCL2, and also would be a subset of the specified `map(any)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your default value is a list of maps, but it should be only map:

```
      "default": {
         "acct1": "000000000001",
         "acct2": "000000000002"
      }
```